# make custom background of login with google at android

Tags: android

it has google login function with in my app.I want to change the background with custom image . Anyone can help me please I spend many hours for searching but cannot find the correct answer. here is my code

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/google_login"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_policy"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/pager_indicator"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/google_64"
        />
```

Comment: do you want to change color of google login button ?

Comment: cant you change background of this button, change image by replacing "@drawable/google_64" to "#fff"

Comment: i want to replace the whole background with single image..

Comment: You cannot change background of this button. Check this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Image in drawable folder. Here my image file name is left.png

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/google_login"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_policy"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/pager_indicator"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left"
        android:background="@null"
        />
```

Comment: custom image and google origin background is overlap . can hide origin background ?